# Check Constraints using Functions

Tags: sql-server

I was taking some time trying to write a check constraint that is pointed to a function and I found this article about it:

[article about check constraints using functions](http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2011/08/08/check-constraints-that-call-functions/)

My question is: Check Constraints are definitively a better option than triggers?

here you have an example:

```
CREATE TABLE tmgr.MyTable
(
id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
NAME NVARCHAR(50),
TypeId int
)

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CheckConstraintType 
(   
    @Entity nvarchar(128),
    @TypeId int 
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue INT = 0
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM dbo.TypeEntity
            WHERE Entityid = ( SELECT Entityid
                     FROM dbo.Entity
                    WHERE Name = @Entity
                     )
              AND TypeId = @TypeId)
           SET @ReturnValue = 1 
    RETURN  @ReturnValue
END
```

Here you have the check constraint

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MyTable_CheckConstraintType CHECK (dbo.fn_CheckConstraintType('MyTableType', [TypeId])=1)
```

I want to be sure that this approach is the best option or there is any other option before using triggers. Check Constraints happen before the insert/update statement is this the main different of using triggers? too many question! sorry!

Thanks